# MySQL- Counting rows VS Setting up a counter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables **`posts`**`<id, user_id, text, votes_counter, created>` and **`votes`**`<id, post_id, user_id, vote>`. Here the table vote can be either 1 (upvote) or -1(downvote). Now if I need to fetch the total votes(upvotes - downvotes) on a post, I can do it in 2 ways.

1. Use **`count(*)`** to count the number of upvotes and downvotes on that post from `votes` table and then do the maths.
2. Set up a counter column `votes_counter` and increment or decrement it everytime a user upvotes or downvotes. Then simply extract that `votes_counter`.

My question is which one is better and under what condition. By saying condition, I mean factors like scalability, peaktime et cetera.

To what I know, if I use method 1, for a table with millions of rows, **`count(*)`** could be a heavy operation. To avoid that situation, if I use a counter then during peak time, the votes_counter column might get deadlocked, too many users trying to update the counter!

Is there a third way better than both and as simple to implement?

Comment: "the votes_counter column might get deadlocked, too many users trying to update the counter" --- why should it be a deadlock here?

Comment: @zerkms I mean not technically deadlocked! Say, 1000 users are trying to vote on one post every one second. But the database server can't handle 1000 operations in a second. That's the kind of situation I'm talking about.

Comment: when you have 1000 users that simultaneously do something on your site - incrementing a single counter won't be the thing you need to worry about.

Comment: @zerkms Well, this is for my university simulation project. 1K user a second for real is a big thing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two approaches represent a common tradeoff between complexity of implementation and speed.

- The first approach is very simple to implement, because it does not require you to do any additional coding.
- The second approach is potentially a lot faster, especially when you need to count a small percentage of items in a large table
- The first approach can be sped up by well designed indexes. Rather than searching through the whole table, your RDBMS could retrieve a few records from the index, and do the counts using them

The second approach can become very complex very quickly:

- You need to consider what happens to the counts when a user gets deleted
- You should consider what happens when the table of votes is manipulated by tools outside your program. For example, merging records from two databases may prove a lot more complex when the current counts are stored along with the individual ones.

I would start with the first approach, and see how it performs. Then I would try optimizing it with indexing. Finally, I would consider going with the second approach, possibly writing triggers to update counts automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As this sounds a lot like StackExchange, I'll refer you to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) on the meta about the database schema used on the site. The votes table looks like this:

**Votes table:**

- `Id`
- `PostId`
- `VoteTypeId`, one of the following values:

  ```
  1 - AcceptedByOriginator
  2 - UpMod
  3 - DownMod
  4 - Offensive
  5 - Favorite (if VoteTypeId = 5, UserId will be populated)
  6 - Close
  7 - Reopen
  8 - BountyStart (if VoteTypeId = 8, UserId will be populated)
  9 - BountyClose
  10 - Deletion
  11 - Undeletion
  12 - Spam
  15 - ModeratorReview  
  16 - ApproveEditSuggestion
  ```
- `UserId` (only present if VoteTypeId is 5 or 8)
- `CreationDate`
- `BountyAmount` (only present if VoteTypeId is 8 or 9)

And so based on that it sounds like the way it would be run is:

```
SELECT VoteTypeId FROM Votes WHERE VoteTypeId = 2 OR VoteTypeId = 3
```

And then based on the value, do the maths:

```
int score = 0;
for each vote in voteQueryResults
    if(vote == 2) score++;
    if(vote == 3) score--;
```

Even with millions of results, this is probably going to be a very fast operation as it's so simple.

Comment: This is not that fast on Stack Overflow since they also cache the score. If you expand the score that operation takes a while and because of that this operation is only available to 2k+ users